# SQL standard in SQL Server and postrgesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

does anybody can explain to me why this statement returns columns which are FK in SQL Server but in postgresql returns nothing?

Table is identical on both RDBMS and do have FKs

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu, 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
where ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
  and ccu.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
  and tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

Comment: Checked for case sensitivity of table names?

Comment: when I remove "and tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'" in postgresql it returns columns whith constraint type = check or columns whith constraint type = primary key. So case sensitivity is OK.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that SQL Server stores "outgoing" foreign keys whereas PostgreSQL stores "incoming" foreign keys.

SQL Server example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57493/3 
PostgreSQL example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/57493/5

Unfortunately the ANSI standard doesn't say which one is correct. It merely says:

> *TABLE_CONSTRAINTS base table
>
>  
>   The values of CONSTRAINT_TYPE have the following meanings:
>
>   FOREIGN KEY: The constraint being described is a foreign key constraint.
>
>   ...*

Comment: I wish I had the energy to define and publish a set of views that would standardise this stuff over all RDBMS's. Alas ...